# Как встроить конфигурационный файл в приложение c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

По этому вопросу было много ответов, только ничего не подходит, поскольку склеивание файла лишает смысла всю программу, и я пишу в файл настройки, меняющие поведение приложения. .NET Framework 4.5.2.

В приложение должна входить эта настройка:

```
<runtime>
  <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures=false" />
</runtime>
```

Comment: в 4.6+ есть `AppContext.SetSwitch`, который как раз и решает эту проблему. В 4.5.2 аналога не нашел. И вы опять не казали для условия, что сборка под 4.5.2 а запуск под 4.7.2...

Comment: Я смотрю, это только для bool. Во-вторых, в поиске написано, что это не работает.

Comment: `AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures", false);` вот так будет, и оно работает, но только для 4.6 +. Если из имени параметра убрать префикс "Switch.", то работать не будет

Comment: А можно в двух словах о чём идет речь? Не понятно, как связано "Как встроить конфигурационный файл в приложение c#"  и содержание вопроса и ответа. Что-то осталось за кадром? Добавьте, пожалуйста ссылку на связанные вопросы. Спаcи6о.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы exe.config не лежал рядом с программой, а находился внутри нее, без каких-либо склейщиков.

Comment: @4per это секция конфига runtime, в 4.5.2 я не нашел способа получить доступ к этим параметрам из приложения. В старших версиях все просто. А вопрос с ответом связаны вот этой строчкой "AppContextSwitchOverrides", независимо от конкретного свича который нужно использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел одно решение, но оно довольно "грязное", смотрите сами использовать или нет.

Так как [AppContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to) и сами переключатели появились только в версии 4.6, то 4.5.2 и меньше просто ни чего о них не знают и компилятор не позволяет использовать класс `AppContext`, так как приложение должно уметь запускаться на целевой версии фреймворка. Через настройки AppConfig это работает, т.к. его читает уже реальная среда исполнения, которая знает что и как с ними нужно делать.

Чтобы обойти ограничение 4.5.2 можно воспользоваться записью в [реестр](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.appcontext?view=netframework-4.8#appcontext-for-library-consumers), но сделать запись в реестре нужно до активации формы, в методе main, иначе опция будет проигнорирована. Получится что-то такое:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        //создаем ключ и нужные значения при запуске
        var HKLM = Registry.LocalMachine;
        var sw = HKLM.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AppContext");
        sw.SetValue("Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures", "false");
        //активируем оконную часть приложения
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        //удаляем ключ при завершении, чтобы не мусорить в системе,     
        //может быть лучше вынести в событие FormClosed
        HKLM.DeleteSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AppContext");
    }
}
```

**Важно! Запись в данную ветку реестра требует повышения привилегий до уровня администратора системы и повлияет на все .NET приложения.**

Ключ реестра указан для Win10x64, конфигурация сборки AnyCPU. Для других версий ОС 
 и конфигурации сборки может потребоваться корректировка, например такая `@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AppContext"`. Но с этим я уже не экспериментировал.

Comment: Я про этот метод уже читал, но работаю с неуправляемым кодом, поэтому программа может в любой момент упасть.

Comment: @Antinet ну альтератив все равно не нашел, подождем, может кто-то что-то лучше предложит. А почему обязательно 4.5.2, более свежую версию использовать совсем никак?

Comment: В принципе, можно, но очень нежелательно.